# No idea why I am getting "ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base10: '' "

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

```
window = tk. Tk()  #creates a new window
age = StringVar()
window.title("Are you old enough to smoke?")  #title
window.geometry("300x200")  #window size
window.wm_iconbitmap('favicon.ico')  #icon

photo = tk.PhotoImage(file="images.png")  #picture in said window
w = tk.Label(window, image=photo)
w.pack()

lbl=tk.Label(window, text="Please enter your age.", bg="light salmon", fg="blue2")  #label text & color
lbl.pack()

ent = tk.Entry(window, text="(Your age here)", textvariable=age)
ent.pack()


def callback():
    ageint = int(age.get())
#Line causing error RIP^
    if ageint >= 18:
        mess = 'You are legally able to smoke cigarettes.'
    elif ageint <= 12:
        mess = "You're to young to smoke,\nGet out of here."
    else:
        mess = "You are not of legal age to smoke."

    if ageint >= 21:
        mess += "\nYou are legally able to smoke marijuana."
    if ageint >= 40:
        mess += "\nYou're above the age of forty,\nDo you really need to ask 

    messagebox.showinfo(title="Can you Smoke", message=mess)

btn = tk.Button(window, text="Confirm", bg="sienna1", fg="blue2", relief="groove", command=callback)
btn.pack()
```

There is my code. Every thing works great when I run my program (very simple little practice thing) it sometimes work and displays the correct message. but sometimes my messagebox does not show up and this error appears in the console:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1533, in __call__
        return self.func(*args)
      File "C:/Users/Josh/Documents/Trial Python Programs/Smoke window Program.py", line 22, in callback
        ageint = int(age.get(), base=3)
    ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

I have found many topics relating to the issue, but none that specifically help me (or atleast that I understand). I am just confused because sometimes it happens and sometimes it does not. Any help/tips would be greatly appreciated.

Background info:

1. Python34
2. Win7-64 bit
3. I've been doing this for less than a week go easy on me please.
4. I only provided the amount of code that I thought was needed.

Comment: I belive the problem is `int(age.get())` if it gets a decimal it gives the same error you're getting

Comment: If you put in a decimal in the entry shouldn't it as a normal number? Like if I put 18.5 wouldnt it just see it as half way between 18 and 19? (That is just logic in my head, nothing to do with actual knowledge of how the code works). If it does not, is there a way to make it so it does? I also don't understand why it would still only happen sometimes when you enter a whole number.

Comment: could you try changing `int()` to `float()` and see if that works

Comment: As I posted that I got an error again.  this time it says    ValueError: could not convert string to float:

Comment: look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8420143/valueerror-could-not-convert-string-to-float-id

Comment: I want to say I was able to fix my problem with it, but I was not.

Comment: The error message gives you a good hint: `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''`. Those empty quotes at the end is the empty string you tried to convert to an int. So, your program is operating normally, it just caught bad input from the user (in this case, no data was entered). Catch the exception and show a "Try following instructions" message box.

Comment: The error does not only happen when you do not put anything in the entry box. you can put in a full entry box and the error will still happen. What seems to be happening is when I open the program, right there it decides if it is going to reply to everything with an error.

Answer (score 2):

As @tdelaney says in its comment, the error message says that the `StringVar age` is empty.

You can test that age contains an int representation (via a regex) before trying to convert it to an int

```
import re
intre = re.compile("\d+")
...
if intre.match(age.get):
    ageint = int(age.get())
    ...
else:
    # warn the user for invalid input
```

You can also use the *optimistic* way: it should be good, and just test exceptional conditions

```
...
try:
    ageint = int(age.get())
except ValueError:
    # warn the user for invalid input
```

In that case, you would better use directly an `IntVar` for age:

```
age = IntVar()
...
try:
    ageint = age.get()
...
```

But if you want to make sure that user can only type digits in the `Entry`, you should use `validate` and `validatecommand` options. Unfortunately they are poorly documented in `Tkinter` world, and the best reference I could find are 2 other SO posts, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8960839) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4140988)

Answer (score 1):

This could make your program more stable:

```
def callback():
    try:
        ageint = int(float(age.get()))
    except ValuError:
        mess = "Please enter a valid number."
        messagebox.showinfo(title="Invalid Input", message=mess)
        return
    if ageint >= 18:
    # rest of your code
```