# NameError, name not defined

Tags: python, tkinter

I've defined an `Entry` in `def` then use it in simple math function. When I type in number in `Entry` it says name (of `Entry`) is not defined.

I'm very new at programing and this is an school project. In this project I'm trying to make value calculator.

```
marka1=float(marka.get())*1*3.79
NameError: name 'marka' is not defined
```

Code:

```
from  tkinter import*

prozor1=Tk()
prozor1.title('Python')
prozor1.geometry('500x500')
prozor1.config(bg= 'yellow')
natpis1=Label(prozor1, text='Konverter valuta')
natpis1.place(x=200, y=50)
natpis1.config(font=36)
natpis1.config(bg='silver')
natpis1.config(fg='black')
suma1=Entry(prozor1, width=19)
suma1.place(x=200,y=100)
mb=Menubutton(prozor1, text='Valuta')
mb.place(x=27, y=100)
mb.menu=Menu(mb)
mb.config(bg='grey')
mb['menu']=mb.menu

def km1():
    marka1=float(marka.get())*1*3.79
    rezu3=Label(prozor1, text='KN='+str(marka1))
    rezu3.place(x=200, y=170)
    rezu3.config(bg='silver')
def KM1():
    frk=Button(prozor1, text='Pretvori',width=15, command=km1)
    frk.place(x=200,y=130)
    frk.config(bg='silver')
    natpis1=Label(prozor1, text='Unesi sumu u KM')
    natpis1.place(x=90, y=100)
    natpis1.config(bg='silver')
    marka=Entry(prozor1, width=19)
    marka.place(x=200,y=100)

mb.menu.add_command(label='KM-KN', command=KM1)
```

This is an important part of the project.

Comment: `marka` only exists within the scope of KM1, it doesnt exist in the scope of km1

Comment: `import *` is generally bad practice. You should use more whitespace in your program, it's very difficult to parse, it feels like a brick wall.

Answer (score 1):

In your case `marka` needs to be passed into the function. In order to do this you will need to create the variable earlier in your code. Here is what works for me:

```
def km1(marka):
    marka1=float(marka.get())*1*3.79
    rezu3=Label(prozor1, text='KN='+str(marka1))
    rezu3.place(x=200, y=170)
    rezu3.config(bg='silver')
def KM1():
    marka=Entry(prozor1, width=19)
    marka.place(x=200,y=100)
    frk=Button(prozor1, text='Pretvori',width=15, command=lambda: km1(marka))
    frk.place(x=200,y=130)
    frk.config(bg='silver')
    natpis1=Label(prozor1, text='Unesi sumu u KM')
    natpis1.place(x=90, y=100)
    natpis1.config(bg='silver')
```

(Also, this does present another issue with form validations, [this might help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8959815/restricting-the-value-in-tkinter-entry-widget))

Comment: Passing the function as an argument is a good suggestion, but you're doing it wrong. The `command=km1(marka)` is going to call `km1()` _when the `Button` is being created_ and set its callback function to `None` because that's what `kmb1()` returns. A correct way would be `command=lambda: km1(marka)`.

Comment: Spot on. Thanks for the correction! Have edited the response.

Answer (score 0):

In python there are something called [local and global](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/python/local-and-global-variables-in-python) variables. You define `marka` inside a function, so the rest of your code can't see it. At the beginning of your `def KM1` you need to insert a line like this:

```
def KM1:
    global marka
    […]
```

So that the variable becomes global, and your whole code can see it

Comment: While this would work, it's best to avoid global variables as much as possible — and there are ways to solve the problem and avoid them.