# Tkinter and while and for

Tags: python, for-loop, tkinter, while-loop

I cant use bucles with tkinter cause it stops responding, i tried with while and for, i know there are more questions like this but i didnt understood, so guys please help me, i need ur help and yes im writting more because this isnt letting me post cause i have to add details

````
import time



spam_delay=0.001
spam_keys="cerdo"
spam_range=70
class spammer():
    def __init__(self,delay,keys):
        self.delay=spam_delay
        self.keys=spam_keys
        self.started=False

    **def start(self):
        self.started=True
        self.run()
    def run(self):
            if self.started:
                for i in range(spam_range):
                    time.sleep(spam_delay)
                    pyautogui.typewrite(spam_keys)
                    pyautogui.press("enter")
                    time.sleep(0.1)**
                    
    def stop(self):
        if self.started:
            self.started=False

spamerV2=spammer(spam_delay,spam_keys)

from tkinter import *

root=Tk()
root.title("Spammer_V2.0")
root.resizable(1,1)

Frame=Frame(root, width=400, height=600)
Frame.pack()

Label=Label(Frame, text="papu")
Label.grid(row=0, column=0,sticky="e", padx=10,pady=10)

Entry_Text=Entry(Frame)
Entry_Text.grid(row=0, column=1,sticky="e", padx=10,pady=10)
**btn=Button(root,text="papuu",command=spamerV2.start)
btn.pack()**
btn2=Button(root,text="apaga", command=spamerV2.stop)
btn2.pack()


root.mainloop()```
````

Comment: Could you clarify your question? What specifically isn't working, and what line is it happening on? SO's great for asking questions that might benefit other people with the same question, so if you edit yours to suit that purpose, it might be easier to answer.

Comment: thanks for reading, the problem is in the function run() because i use a bucle so at the end of the code the variable "btn" looks for that function and when i press the button it says "Spammer is  not responding" and i have to close the program and wait until windows find a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The loop in the `run` method uses `sleep` so the application freezes until the loop is done (about 20 seconds). Use the `after` method instead for your 'loop'.

I also added a textbox for the spam text and delay

Here is the updated code:

```
import time

spam_delay=0.001
spam_keys="cerdo"
spam_range=70
class spammer():
    def __init__(self,delay,keys):
        self.delay=spam_delay
        self.keys=spam_keys
        self.started=False
        self.ctr = 0

    def start(self):
        self.started=True
        global spam_keys,spam_delay
        spam_keys = Entry_Text.get() or 'cerdo'  # spam text
        spam_delay = float(Entry_Delay.get())   # delay
        self.run()
    def run(self):
            if self.started:
                time.sleep(spam_delay)
                pyautogui.typewrite(spam_keys)
                pyautogui.press("enter")
                #time.sleep(0.1)
                self.ctr += 1
                if self.ctr < spam_range:
                   root.after(500, self.run)  # ms
                else:
                   self.ctr=0
                    
    def stop(self):
        if self.started:
            self.started=False
            self.ctr=0

spamerV2=spammer(spam_delay,spam_keys)

from tkinter import *
import pyautogui

root=Tk()
root.title("Spammer_V2.0")
root.resizable(1,1)

Frame=Frame(root, width=400, height=600)
Frame.pack()

Label=Label(Frame, text="papu")
Label.grid(row=0, column=0,sticky="e", padx=10,pady=10)

Entry_Text=Entry(Frame)
Entry_Text.grid(row=0, column=1,sticky="e", padx=10,pady=10)
Entry_Text.delete(0, END)
Entry_Text.insert(0, "cerdo")
Entry_Delay=Entry(Frame)
Entry_Delay.grid(row=0, column=2,sticky="e", padx=10,pady=10)
Entry_Delay.delete(0, END)
Entry_Delay.insert(0, "1")
btn=Button(root,text="papuu",command=spamerV2.start)
btn.pack()
btn2=Button(root,text="apaga", command=spamerV2.stop)
btn2.pack()


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: omg, thank you it works but i have another question, its kinda stupid but im new, how can i make a entryText that would storage the text the person wrote there in variables, for example one entry for spamdelay, another one for spam keys etc..

Comment: Answer updated with new text box

Comment: THANKS!!! Just one more question, how can i make that in the delay entry box people can´t write letters, i want only numbers in that entry please!

Comment: That is somewhat complicated: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8959815/restricting-the-value-in-tkinter-entry-widget. It may be easier to remove any letters when the user clicks the button (or show an error).

Comment: Ok bro, you are a genius

Comment: Bro, how can i make like another screen and put my autoclicker to have spammer and auto clicker in the same app