# How to restrict keyboard input in Python

Tags: python, sudoku

I am writing a sudoku program in python using tkinter. I would like to disable all alphabet keys and punctuation keys so that the user only inputs numbers. Is it possible to limit the range of the keyboard, or must we only validate to solve this problem?

Comment: This answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8960839/14316282) probably answers your question

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Restricting the value in Tkinter Entry widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8959815/restricting-the-value-in-tkinter-entry-widget)